# Why call static linker instead of preprocessor?

Tags: linker, preprocessor, static-libraries

Suppose we have a static library and we want to use it for our main.c file, now the question is

Why we must call the linker (ld) ? since all we do is copy - pasting the code from our static lib in our main.c file ?

Couldn't the preprocessor deal with that ?

Comment: Yes, it could, but it doesn't.

Comment: @StuartSiegler are there any reasons why it doesn't ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It *could* do it, in exactly the same way you could use a fish to fell a tree. It's not really the job it was designed to do.

The preprocessor phase is meant to morph the **source** code before being given to the compilation phase. Though some may complain about how deficient it seems, it does actually do this job reasonably well.

The linker, on the other hand, does not understand source code at all. It's primary purpose is to tie together **object** files (which may come from C, C++, nasm, gfortran, BCPL or even more bizarre compilers) to create an executable capable of running on the target system.